# Screen Renderering Black

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

after spending a couple of hours making a scene in blender I was exited to render it. The file is a basic scene of a bullet smashing glass. First, I did a test render of a photo, which looked fine, then I set up some key frames for excluding the broken plane and showing the regular plane. That way, when the bullet hit the glass, it would hide the regular plane, and show the broken plane. After setting this up, I did another test render picture, and the screen was black. Please help! Thanks in advance. Here is the .blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ye73c6hymhptk8u/fracturebetter.blend?dl=0

Comment: Upload the blend to Dropbox and link it here